# What's wrong with my Java code please?

Tags: java, copy-constructor

why is my code returning a null value at the last output ?
I it is supposed to return this: Auto MERCEDES C from Garage: TOP SERVICE (x2)
Actualy, the full output should be :
Auto FORD S-MAX from Garage: SPEEDY
Auto FORD FOCUS from Garage: SPEEDY
Auto MERCEDES C from Garage: TOP SERVICE
Auto MERCEDES C from Garage: TOP SERVICE

I know the problem is somewhere in my contructor that conctruct a copy of my object.
Thank you

```
public class Garage {

    //final String naam;
    String naam;

    public Garage (String n){
        this.naam = n;
        }
    public String getName(){
        return naam;
    }

    public void setName(String sn){
        this.naam = sn;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return ""+getName(); 

    }

}

public class Auto {

    //static final String brandName; 
    String brandName;
    Garage garage;

    public Auto(String mn){
        this.brandName = mn;

    }
    public Auto(Auto a){
        this.hashCode();
    }
    public Auto(String mn, Garage g){
        //this(mn);
        this.brandName = mn;
        this.garage = g;
    }

    public String getBranName(){
        return brandName;
    }
    public Garage getGarage(){
        return garage;
    }

    public void setGarage(Garage g){
        this.garage = g;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Auto "+getBranName()+" from Garage: "+getGarage();
    }

}


public class GarageTester {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Auto auto = new Auto("FORD S-MAX");
        Garage garage = new Garage("SPEEDY");
        auto.setGarage(garage);

        System.out.println(auto);

        auto = new Auto("FORD FOCUS",garage);

        System.out.println(auto);

        auto =  new Auto("MERCEDES C", new Garage("TOP SERVICE"));

        System.out.println(auto);

        Auto kopie = new Auto(auto);

        System.out.println(kopie);

    }

}
```

Comment: sorry for the quality of my question

Comment: If you could edit the title to be something a bit more descriptive it would be great. :)

Comment: i'm trying to find a way to edit my title.

Comment: Agree -- your title tells us *nothing* about the problem you're having, and this information will help you get better help and answers. Please read Jon Skeet's blog on [Writing the Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) for more on this.

Comment: You're quite right that *"the problem is somewhere in my contructor that conctruct a copy of my object"*. You haven't implemented it.

Comment: I tried to edit my title dont know how. Thank for helping me out. I'll be more carefull the nex time. cheers

Comment: @user1816151 There's a few buttons near the bottom of your question. One of them lets you edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't implemented your copy constrictor right in the `Auto` class.

```
public Auto(Auto a){
    this.hashCode();
}
```

As of now, it just calls the `hashCode()` method but doesn't initialize the class attributes:

Please correct it as below:

```
public Auto(Auto a){
    this.brandName = a.brandName;
    this.garage = a.garage;
}
```

Once done then `Auto kopie = new Auto(auto);` statement will result into new class instance `kopie` with atributes copied from `auto` instance.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. Next time i'll be more carefull with my title. cheers

Comment: @JBNizet Removed the null check from the constructor.